# how to have multiple conditions in a list comprehension in which conditions are in an array

Tags: python-3.x, vector, list-comprehension

Eg let `A = [3,4]`

and Y be a array of multiple values like 
    `Y = [2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]`
then I want to select all those labels of Y where Y is in A
So I wrote the following code:

```
`Yij = [Y[Y == x] for x in a]`
```

Output:
    `[array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]), array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])]`
but this will lead a list of list.
I on other hand want a normal array.
Any suggestion on how can I make this work?

Comment: Now if I have X as a 2d array like
   [[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
Now I want to find all those X where where the corresponding Y is in a. I tried to do the following 
   [X[Y == j] for j in set(a)] but then it again return a list of 2d arrays but I wanted a normal 2d array. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension solution:

```
>>> A = set([3, 4])
>>> Y = [2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
>>> Z = [y for y in Y if y in A]
>>> Z
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Here are some timings to show the performance difference between using set lookup and list lookup:

```
In [21]: A = set(range(0, 1000, 5))

In [22]: B = list(range(0, 1000, 5))

In [23]: C = list(range(0, 1000))

In [24]: %timeit [y for y in C if y in A]
59.6 µs ± 329 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit [y for y in C if y in B]
2.94 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks! So basically the part y in Y is similar to saying Y[Y]?

Comment: not sure what is Y[Y] but basically I go through each element y in Y, and check if it is in A, if it it is keep y as an entry of Z.

Comment: If you want this to be efficiently scaled to larger solutions, you should convert `A` to a set instead of using `y in A` with a list.  A set has `O(1)` average lookup, while a list will be `O(n)`

Comment: Thanks really interesting, just one query chrisz, how does the lookup decreases in case of the set. Are the sets implemented differently by python, is it indexed or something?

Comment: Sets are indexed.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I added in some timings, if you don't think they contribute to your answer, feel free to delete.

Comment: @chrisz you are awesome. thank you for improving the answer.

Comment: thanks all for  such a quick and insightful response